# How do I display a running count of jquery validation issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I understand how to use numberOfInvalids to get the total number of errors.  What I want is to display this number on the page, and update it whenever it changes.

I know I can do this by calling numberOfInvalids from an onchange or onblur or similar events for every textbox on the form, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Where is the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [showErrors](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) option. It allows you to change how the error messages are displayed, but you can add whatever code you want and then just call `this.defaultShowErrors();` to get the default behavior.

```
$('#form').validate({
    showErrors: function() {
        $('#numberOfInvalids').text(this.numberOfInvalids());
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t100zdj5/)